# Unable to login to Android app using Launchpad OpenID

Tags: bug, android-app, openid

Just took the Stack Exchange Android app for a spin. Since I have an account on Askubuntu.com which is associated with my launchpad.net OpenID account, I selected "Log in".

I then selected "Log in using another OpenID". Since Launchpad was not in the list of login options, I then selected "Manually enter your OpenID".

When I entered my Launchpad OpenID url (launchpad.net/~igadget), I was properly redirected to the Launchpad login page, to which I could successfully login. However, when confirming my details to be shared with Stack Exchange, I got the following message:

> This login is new to Stack Exchange:
>   launchpad.net/~igadget"

I could then only select "Confirm and Create New Account" or Cancel.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?